# Extract values from a .properties file stored in Eclipse project class path using angularJS

Tags: java, eclipse, angularjs, jakarta-ee, properties-file

I have developed a front-end application using AngularJS to hit a REST endpoint. I am using $resource for this. Now, I want to read the url (for that end-point) from a .properties file on my project class path instead of hard-coding it into the controller. How can I proceed to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you are storing properties in url.properties file.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('url.properties').then(function (response) {
    console.log('value1 is ', response.data.value1);
    console.log('value2 is ', response.data.value2);
  });
});
```

You will get all the properties in response.data.*